# Use PHP foreach loop to display data in many html div tags

Tags: php, html

I have the following data and would like to display it in different containers in html.

```
Name    Price   Difference      Signal
CA.PA   15.85   3.5609257364073 MACD
AZN.ST  896     3.4881049471963 MACD
AMGN    258.57  1.6391533819031 SMA 50/200
```

The containers are winner_1. As of right now the first winner_1 display the last Name from the above table.

How can I get it to say CA.PA in the first winner_1, and AZN.ST in the second winner_1, and AMGN in the last winner_1.

```html
         <div class="overview">
             <h1>Winners</h1>
             <div class="winner">
                 <?php
                        foreach ($res_winners_weekly as $r){
                            $name = $r["Name"];
                            $Price = $r['Price'];
                            $percent_diff = $r['Difference'];
                            $signal = $r['Signal'];
                        }
                        ?>
                 <div class="winner_1">
                        <a href="#"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="winner_1">
                        <a href="#"><?php echo $name +1; ?></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="winner_1">

                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

The page can be seen here:
https://signal-invest.com/markets-today/

Comment: You need to output those `div`s inside the loop.

Comment: that at least gets the first winner to be CA.PA, but how to get next Name for winner 2?

Comment: That's what the `foreach` does. It loops through your data row by row. `$r['Name']` will have the name of the current row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is generated div tags using php:

```
<div class="overview">
     <h1>Winners</h1>
     <div class="winner">
         <?php
                foreach ($res_winners_weekly as $r) {
                    $name = $r["Name"];
                    $Price = $r['Price'];
                    $percent_diff = $r['Difference'];
                    $signal = $r['Signal'];

                    echo "<div class='winner_1'>";
                    echo "<a href='#'>{$name}</a>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
          ?>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should see following logic and try doing this way. Hopefully your problem will be resolved.

```
<div class = "overview">
  <h1>Winners</h1>
  <div class = "winner">
    <?php
      foreach ($res_winners_weekly as $r) {
        $name = $r["Name"];
        $Price = $r['Price'];
        $percent_diff = $r['Difference'];
        $signal = $r['Signal'];
        echo "<div class='winner_1'><a href='#'> $name </a></div>";
      }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The logic for the first answer is the same, thanks though.